# AWS EBS volume created using snapshot not showing the previous data

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, mount

I created an EC2 instance and attached EBS volume and mounted to it.then I created a folder in external disk, and mounted 2 folders into that. added those in /etc/fstab. And Ran some docker Images in the mounted volume.
Then I created the snapshot of that EBS volume and created a new volume using the snapshot and attached to another instance. and mounted that as same way how I mounted the first volume.
But After mounting  the volume I did df, it shows the mounted volumes. But I am not able to see any docker Images which was running inside the first volume.
Can anyone help me how can I see the data?

Comment: Could you please explain how you formatted and mounted the EBS the first and then what you did the second time.

Comment: sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvdb
mkdir -p /ext
echo "/dev/xvdb /ext ext4 defaults 0 0" >> /etc/fstab
mount -a
mkdir -p /ext/etc/docker
mkdir -p /ext/var/lib/docker
echo "/dev/xvdb /ext/etc/docker ext4 binds 0 0" >> /etc/fstab
echo "/dev/xvdb /ext/var/lib/docker ext4 binds 0 0" >> /etc/fstab
mount --bind /etc/docker /ext/etc/docker 
mount --bind /var/lib/docker /ext/etc/docker
chown -R 1000 /ext/var/lib/docker
chown -R 1000 /ext/etc/docker.

Comment: This is the first set of commands I given as userdata while launching the EC2 instance.
its storing all docker images in /dev/xvdb when I did df. 

same set of commands only I used while creating another instance with the EBS snapshot. when I did df command there it is showing the usage and file size of /dev/xvdb is 0

Comment: I stopped the instance for creating the EBS snapshot and then added an EBS volume while creating the instance using the created EBS-snapshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the commands you are passing as userdata to your source instance, it looks like you are creating an ext4 filesystem on the disk before first use. You are then using the same commands when utilising the snapshot on the second instance.

Exclude the following on your new instance when mounting the snapshot

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvdb
mkdir -p /ext/etc/docker mkdir -p /ext/var/lib/docker
```